# How do I write a Python test expressing that an assertion should eventually become true?

Tags: python, testing, asynchronous

I'm using Pykka at the moment to program using the Actor model in Python. To me, such simple assertions are essential.

Objective-C has a testing library called [Kiwi](https://github.com/allending/Kiwi/wiki/Asynchronous-Testing) which provides two simple methods for this purpose, for example:

- `[[expectFutureValue(fetchedData) shouldEventually] beNonNil];`
- `[[expectFutureValue(fetchedData) shouldEventuallyBeforeTimingOutAfter(2.0)] equal:@"expected response data"];`

This is both readable and concise. If Objective-C has a library for something like this, Python surely must. But I cannot find one! Help!

Comment: Does anything in [`pykka/tests`](https://github.com/jodal/pykka/tree/develop/tests) help?

Comment: As far as I know there is nothing like that built in to Python.  Just a few questions.  Are these assertions blocking?  What are the differences between "shouldEventually" and "shouldEventuallyBeforeTimingOutAfter"?

Comment: `shouldEventually` is just a convenience method for `shouldEventuallyBeforeTimingOutAfter`. The default timeout is 1 second I think. These assertions do block, yes.